# how to align text to specific character in phpstorm or webstorm?

Tags: php, text, alignment, phpstorm, webstorm

I have this text

```
$test1 = 'testing1';
$test1test1 = 'testing1';
$test1test1test1 = 'testing1';
$test1 = 'testing1';
```

and I would like to align it like this, using tabs,

```
$test1           = 'testing1';
$test1test1      = 'testing1';
$test1test1test1 = 'testing1';
$test1           = 'testing1';
```

is there a way of doing this in phpstorm or webstorm ?

Comment: Is **Align consecutive assignments** option what you are looking for? Check [this blog post](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/10/new-php-formatting-options-in-phpstorm-3-0/).

Comment: ctrl+alt+shft+L  source::
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/10.0/reformatting-source-code.html

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Cmd+Alt+L (in Mac) or Ctrl+Alt+L (Win) and PHP Storm will format code depends of your Code style in Settings. TO set this code style go: 
File -> Settings -> Code style -> PHP(choose here your language) -> Other -> Align key-value pair - mark as checked. And then press Reformat code (Ctrl+Alt+L)  and voila. You will get code, styled you write above.

Comment: Its not working for phpstorm 6.0.3 version although i did setting for this also. Can you help me

Comment: I am using PhpStorm 6.0.3 on Win7 and I have "code reformat" on ALT+F8. That could probably depend on what OS you are using and your keymap setting. Click **Code** -> **Reformat code** in the menu - you should also see your keyboard shortcut by **Reformat code** menu option.

Comment: Note that there is also a setting to align key => value pairs (at least in PHPStorm 6.0.3).  
Great answer thanks.

Comment: Is this also possible for JavaScript? I couldn't find the option there...:/

Comment: In phpStorm 9.x "Align fields in columns".

Answer (score 53):

For me in PhpStorm 8.0.2 I found it here:

> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> PHP -> Wrapping and Braces -> Align consecutive assignments

Comment: The answer provided may be correct but the one @Sam provided is also essential.

Comment: I'm using PHPStorm 2021.2.3,
`Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> PHP -> Wrapping and Braces -> match expression -> Align 'match' arm bodies`

Answer (score 23):

formatting option in `phpstorm 8`

settings > Code Style > php > Wrapping and braces

[image]

check both option
   Align fields in option and Align Constant

now you can get what you want! :)

Source [Jetbrains Blog](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/06/new-and-changed-formatting-options-in-phpstorm-8/)

Comment: "Assignment statement > Align consecutive assignments" also

Comment: Since OP said "align text to specific character, I would also add check **Array Initializers > Align key-value pairs**.

Answer (score 11):

In PhpStorm 8 that option is in:

```
File -> Settings -> Code style -> PHP -> Wrapping and Braces -> Assignment statement
```

Answer (score 6):

A visual update for 2019.1 and newer versions on Mac:

Go to `PHP Storm` > `Preferences` > `Editor` > `Code Style` > `PHP` > `Wrapping and Braces` > `Assignment Statement` > `Align consecutive assignments`.

To activate it go to `Code` > `Reformat Code` or press `Cmd+Opt+L`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We have to check multiple options as below to get

- Problem mentioned above
- Key value pair alignment of array

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case i'm using PHPStorm 2021.2.3,

> `Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> PHP -> Wrapping and Braces -> match expression -> Align 'match' arm bodies`

[image]