# PhpStorm: Align Consecutive Assignments in Javascript

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, code-formatting

In PhpStorm is it possible to have the auto formatter align consecutive assignments in JavaScript? The PHP formatter has the option to align on equals ("+") by checking the "Align consecutive assignments" option in Settings -> Code Style -> PHP -> Other(Tab), but there doesn't seem to be that option for JavaScript, just for colon assignments.

I am using PhpStorm 7.1.3, the latest at the time of writing.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you need v8 for that -- there are some improvements in this area. You can try EAP build here: http://eap.jetbrains.com/phpstorm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using phpstorm 2018.3.5 and I just had to configure this style of alignment for a project I took over.

As sam said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17281308/how-to-align-text-to-specific-character-in-phpstorm-or-webstorm) for php you can set it in :

```
Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> PHP -> Wrapping and Braces -> Align consecutive assignments
```

So I thought it would be the same for JS but it turns out to be slightly different :

```
Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> JavaScript -> Wrapping and Braces -> Variable Declarations -> Align -> When grouped
```

I hope this can help.